# Reducer State Variables returning Undefined State in Tab Navigator Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have three bottom navigation tabs (Captain, Weapon, Engineer). The Captain Tabs displays Current HP & Enemy HP. The Weapon tab displays Enemy HP and 3 buttons. The Engineer Tab displays Current HP and 3 buttons.

I'm trying to display all these various HP values through the use of React Redux and reducers to display all these state variables. However when the various screens get rendered. They all return NaN for the state variables.

**How do we go about returning the default state variables as opposed to returning NaN/undefined for the different tabs?**

Here is my main screen that holds all these tab navigation screens: **Game.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import reducer from '../../src/store/reducer'

import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
    Button

} from 'react-native';

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';


const store = createStore(reducer);

class CaptainScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.hpBar);
        console.log(this.props.enemyBar)

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Text style={styles.title}>Captain Screen</Text>

                <View style={styles.container2} >
                    <Progress.Bar progress={this.props.hpBar} width={200} animated={true} borderColor={'black'} />
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Your HP: {this.props.hpBar * 100}%</Text>
                    <Progress.Bar progress={this.props.enemyBar} width={200} color={'red'} animated={true} borderColor={'black'} />
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Enemy HP: {this.props.enemyBar * 100}%</Text>
                </View>

            </View>
        )



    }
}


class WeaponsScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Weapons Screen</Text>

                <View style={styles.container2} >

                    <Progress.Bar progress={this.props.enemyBar} width={200} color={'red'} animated={true} borderColor={'black'} />
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Enemy HP: {(this.props.enemyBar * 100).toFixed(0)}%</Text>
                    <Button title="Weapon 1" onPress={this.props.onWeapon}> </Button>
                    <Button title="Weapon 2" onPress={() => this.weaponTwo()}> </Button>
                    <Button title="Weapon 3" onPress={() => this.weaponThree()}> </Button>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

}

class EngineersScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Engineer Screen</Text>

                <View style={styles.container2} >

                    <Progress.Bar progress={this.props.hpBar} width={200} animated={true} borderColor={'black'} />
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Your HP: {(this.props.hpBar * 100).toFixed(0)}%</Text>

                    <Button title="Quick Fix" onPress={() => this.quickFix()}> </Button>
                    <Button title="Medium Fix" onPress={() => this.mediumFix()}> </Button>
                    <Button title="Indepth Fix" onPress={() => this.indepthFix()}> </Button>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const TabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Captain: {
            screen: CaptainScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <View>
                        <Icon name="ship-wheel" style={[{ color: tintColor }]} size={25} />
                    </View>
                ),
            }
        },
        Weapons: {
            screen: WeaponsScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <View>
                        <Icon name="pistol" style={[{ color: tintColor }]} size={25} />
                    </View>
                ),
                activeColor: '#ffffff',
                inactiveColor: '#a3c2fa',
                barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#2163f6' },
            }
        },
        Engineer: {
            screen: EngineersScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <View>
                        <Icon name="hammer" style={[{ color: tintColor }]} size={25} />
                    </View>
                ),
                activeColor: '#ffffff',
                inactiveColor: '#92c5c2',
                barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#2c6d6a' },
            }
        },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Captain',
        activeColor: '#ffffff',
        inactiveColor: '#bda1f7',
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#6948f4' },
    }
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        hpBar: state.hpBar,
        enemyBar: state.enemyBar
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onEngineer: () => dispatch({ type: 'HP_UP', payload: 0.1 }),
        onWeapon: () => dispatch({ type: 'HP_DOWN', payload: 0.1 })


    }
}

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TabNavigator);

const Game = createAppContainer(ConnectedApp);


export default Root = () => {
    return (<Provider store={store}><Game /></Provider>)
}
```

Here is my reducer file: **Reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
    hpBar: 1.0,
    enemyBar: 1.0,


};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const newState = { ...state };

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'HP_UP':
            return {
                ...state,
                hpBar: state.hpBar + action.payload
            }
            break;

        case 'HP_DOWN':

            return {
                ...state,
                enemyBar: state.enemyBar - action.payload,

            }
            break;

    }


    return newState;
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you provided shows that state.hpBar would be NaN. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? [Here](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/cf93d154958207b4f938ec58e45ffbde) is code to produce a runnable stack snippet.

Comment: @HMR I have edited my codebase with the relevant information that's giving me this problem. I believe the problem, if it is our own, lies somewhere with regards to how the store connects to the UI of the 3 tabs. I had console logged the mapStateToProps and it returned the initial state values given in the reducer correctly (hpBar: 1, enemyBar: 1). However, when we console logged the props in the Captain Screen these same state variables were returned undefined.

Comment: Try to make a ConnectedCapatin and pass that to `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` I think the props are not passed from the navigator to the component it renders so no use in connecting TabNavigator

Comment: @HMR Hey HMR, this problem persists in all the tabs (Captain, Weapons and Engineer) tabs they both have state variables defined in the reducer as NaN, I'm not sure if I'm connecting it correctly? Any insight on this in the meantime I am going to try what you suggested in the last post.